# Camera freeze while zooming react-native-vision-camera

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native, mobile-development, react-native-vision-camera

I'm implementing vision camera in my react native application where user can capture the images. I've enabled 'enableZoomGesture' to true and it is causing crash in my iPhone13. How can this be fixed?

Here is the code snipppet of my camera component what i have tried in my application

```
      <Camera 
          ref={cameraRef}
          orientation="portrait"
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
          device={device}
          torch={flashOn ? 'on' : 'off'}
          isActive={isCameraActive}
          enableZoomGesture
          zoom={zoom}
          focusable
          video={type === 'video' ? true : false}
          photo={type === 'photo' ? true : false}
          audio={isAudioPermission}
          resizeMode="cover"
          pixelFormat="native"
          format={cameraFormat}
          onInitialized={onCameraInitialized}
          onError={(error: CameraRuntimeError) => {
            console.log('CameraRuntimeError =============>> ', error.cause);
          }}
        />
```

this is the error I got in my log statement

[Error: [-11819]: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 “Cannot Complete Action” UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later.}]